# Javascript in another location

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I am making a jQuery Mobile and Phonegap application. It works very well on Chrome, Safari and Firefox, but on android device it doesn't. I search a bit and I think that my problem lies in .js files localized in another folder. They don't seem to be added/loaded to my app. That the example that does not work:

```
    $('#contact_add').live('vclick', function(event) {
                $.showPageLoadingMsg;
                **clearContactStorage();**
                window.location.href = ('file:///C:/Users/add.html');
            });
```

Here is head definition:

```
<script src="file:///android_asset/www/js/clearStorage.js"></script>
```

And here is the function in .js file:

```
function clearContactStorage()
{
window.localStorage.setItem('uwagi', 'Uwagi...');
window.localStorage.setItem('idCustomerLabel', 'Kontrahent...');
console.log('Cleaning contactStorage');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your need to change the source of your javascript file:

Change:

```
<script src="file:///C:/Users/Praktykant/workspace/TopFirma/assets/www/js/clearStorage.js"></script>
```

To:

```
<script src="./js/clearStorage.js"></script>
```

The paths you define for the sources must take into account that your folder `www` is the root folder.

If it's not working, you may need to transfer all the javascript functions defined in your file `clearStorage.js` to your HTML file (in `<script>` tags)

Let me know if this works

Comment: Not sure if the dot "." is needed before "js/clearStorage.js", but definitely it'll work without it

Comment: Yes normally you can skip the './' . The thing is, when you refer a source that is in your folder `www`, you have to consider that `www` is the root folder

Comment: Normally my path to the js file is: file:///android_asset/www/js/bla.js That does not seen to be a problem. Scripts worked in my html files, but I was duplicating a lot of code. Do you know any other solution??

Comment: What do you mean by duplicating?

Comment: writing the same, long code in many files (realy a lot of). Eclipse doesn't like it:)